# How do you activate fadeOut effect using Tone.JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tonejs

I am able to successfully play oscillating tone of type square-wave with 100hz frequency.

However, the tone does not "gracefully" stop. Moreover, your speakers will make a "thud" sound when the tone stops, and the "thud" is worse when your speaker volume is too high. To fix that, I would like to add a fadeOut effect. [ToneJS](https://tonejs.github.io/) library supports this: [here](https://tonejs.github.io/docs/14.7.77/Player.html#fadeOut). However, I am not able to set the fadeOut property or activate it.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
$( "#btnPlay" ).click(function(e) {
  var player = new Tone.Oscillator(100, "square").toDestination();

  player.fadeOut = 5; // set fadeOut time value

  player.start();
  player.stop(1); // stop playing after 1 second
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tone/14.8.5/Tone.js"></script>

<input id = "btnPlay" type="submit" value="Play!"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `fadeOut` value is too long so you won't hear it. The value is in seconds, so try providing `0.05` (i.e. `50ms`) instead.

```
player.fadeOut = 0.05; // value is in seconds
```